# Why doesn't postresql use all columns in a multi-column index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance, postgresql-11

I am using the extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
```

I have an index that looks like this...

```
create index boundaries2 on rets USING GIN(source, isonlastsync, status, (geoinfo::jsonb->'boundaries'), ctcvalidto, searchablePrice, ctcSortOrder);
```

before I started messing with it, the index looked like this, with the same results that I'm about to share, so it seems minor variations in the index definition don't make a difference:

```
create index boundaries on rets USING GIN((geoinfo::jsonb->'boundaries'), source, status, isonlastsync, ctcvalidto, searchablePrice, ctcSortOrder);
```

I give pgsql 11 this query:

```
explain analyze select id from rets where ((geoinfo::jsonb->'boundaries' ?| array['High School: Torrey Pines']) AND source='SDMLS'
          AND searchablePrice>=800000 AND searchablePrice<=1200000 AND YrBlt>=2000 AND EstSF>=2300
         AND Beds>=3 AND FB>=2 AND ctcSortOrder>'2019-07-05 16:02:54 UTC' AND Status IN ('ACTIVE','BACK ON MARKET')
         AND ctcvalidto='9999-12-31 23:59:59 UTC' AND isonlastsync='true') order by LstDate desc, ctcSortOrder desc LIMIT 3000;
```

with result...

```
 Limit  (cost=120.06..120.06 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=472.849..472.850 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=120.06..120.06 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=472.847..472.848 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: lstdate DESC, ctcsortorder DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on rets  (cost=116.00..120.05 rows=1 width=23) (actual time=472.748..472.841 rows=1 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((source = 'SDMLS'::text) AND (((geoinfo)::jsonb -> 'boundaries'::text) ?| '{"High School: Torrey Pines"}'::text[]) AND (ctcvalidto = '9999-12-31 23:59:59+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (searchableprice >= 800000) AND (searchableprice <= 1200000) AND (ctcsortorder > '2019-07-05 16:02:54+00'::timestamp with time zone))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 93
               Filter: (isonlastsync AND (yrblt >= 2000) AND (estsf >= 2300) AND (beds >= 3) AND (fb >= 2) AND (status = ANY ('{ACTIVE,"BACK ON MARKET"}'::text[])))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 10
               Heap Blocks: exact=102
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on boundaries2  (cost=0.00..116.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=471.762..471.762 rows=104 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((source = 'SDMLS'::text) AND (((geoinfo)::jsonb -> 'boundaries'::text) ?| '{"High School: Torrey Pines"}'::text[]) AND (ctcvalidto = '9999-12-31 23:59:59+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (searchableprice >= 800000) AND (searchableprice <= 1200000) AND (ctcsortorder > '2019-07-05 16:02:54+00'::timestamp with time zone))
 Planning Time: 0.333 ms
 Execution Time: 474.311 ms
(14 rows)
```

**The Question**

Why are the columns `status` and `isonlastsync` not used by the `Bitmap Index Scan on boundaries2`?

Comment: reason for close vote?!

Answer (score 1):

It can do so if it predicts that filtering out those columns will be faster. This is usually the case if cardinality on columns is very low and you will fetch large enough portion of all rows; this is true for `boolean` like `isonlastsync` and usually true for status columns with just a few distinct values.

`Rows Removed by Filter: 10` this is very little to filter out, either because your table does not hold large number of rows or most of them fit into condition you specified for those two columns. You might try generating more data in that table or selecting rows with rare status.

I suggest doing [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) (with WHERE condition), at least for `boolean` value and remove those two columns to make this index a bit more lightweight.

Comment: You are correct, both `isonlastsync` and `status` have low cardinality, but so does `source`, so why are the two fields singled out? Is there any tuning parameter or other work-around to force pgsql to disregard low cardinality to help validate this theory?

Comment: @AlexR Maybe you could tweak [settings of costs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) for certain operations: `cpu_index_tuple_cost`, `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost` seem relevant. I did something similar in the past but I do not remember if it was exactly the same case like yours and if it worked (making seq_page_cost higher did certainly make Postgres less likely to perform seq_scan). I'm sadly not that familiar with internals of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you why, but I can help you optimize the query.

You should *not* use a multi-column GIN index, but a GIN index on only the `jsonb` expression and a b-tree index on the other columns.

The order of columns matters: put the oned used in an equality condition first, with the most selective in the beginning. Next put the column with the must selective inequality or `IN` conditions. For the following columns, the order doesn't matter, as they will only act as filters in the index scan.

Make sure that the indexes are cached in RAM.

I'd expect you to be faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking yourself the wrong question. As Lukasz answered already, PostgreSQL may find inefficient to check all columns in the index. The problem here is that your index is too big on disk.

Probably by trying to make this SQL faster you added as many columns as possible to the index, but it is backfiring.

The trick is to realize how much data PostgreSQL has to read to find your records. If your index contains too much data, it will have to read a lot. Also, be aware that low cardinality columns don't play well with BTree and common index types; generally you want to avoid indexing them.

To have an index as small as possible and it's quick to do lookups you have to find the column with more cardinality, or better, the column that will return less rows for your query. My guess is "ctcSortOrder". This will be the first column of your index.

Now look, after filtering by the 1st column, which column has now the most cardinality or will filter out most rows. I have no idea on your data, but "source" looks like a good candidate.

Try to avoid jsonb searches unless they are the primary source of the cardinality, and keep the index as a Btree. BTree is several times faster.

And like Lukasz suggested, look on partial indexes. For example add "WHERE Status IN ('ACTIVE','BACK ON MARKET') AND isonlastsync='true'" as these two may be common for all your searches.

Bottom line is, having a simpler, smaller index is faster than having all columns indexed. And the order of the columns does matter a lot. Stick with BTree unless there is a good reason (lots of cardinality in non-btree compatible types).

If your table is huge (>10M rows) consider table partitioning, for example by ctcSortOrder. But I don't think this is your case.

Comment: I wouldn't consider 10 millions rows "huge" ;)

Comment: No, it's just "big". But from my experience less than that and partitioning has no noticeable effects at all, compared with partial indexes.